# ruby or python for use with sqlite database?

Tags: python, ruby, sqlite

Which of these two languages interfaces better and delivers a better performance/toolset for working with sqlite database?  I am familiar with both languages but need to choose one for a project I'm developing and so I thought I would ask here. I don't believe this to be opinionated as performance of a language is pretty objective.

Comment: Hate to say it, but performance/toolset quality is not really objective unless you are very specific about the facet of performance you're interested in (e.g. this is my exact schema, can I handle X reads/second). That being said, python has a `sqlite3` module built in that I've had plenty of success with. Can't say anything about ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good reason to choose one over the other as far as sqlite performance or usability.

Both languages have perfectly usable (and pythonic/rubyriffic) sqlite3 bindings.

In both languages, unless you do something stupid, the performance is bounded by the sqlite3 performance, not by the bindings.

Neither language's bindings are missing any uncommon but sometimes performance-critical functions (like an "exec many", manual transaction management, etc.).

There may be language-specific frameworks that are better or worse in how well they integrate with sqlite3, but at that point you're choosing between frameworks, not languages.